# how to merge 2 different user names of a single user

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I ended up with 2 user names for seasoned chef, I don't know how to merge them together, so that I get mails to the single inbox

Comment: Go to http://cooking.stackexchange.com/contact (assuming that's the site you're referring to) and choose the option to merge profiles.